# How can I convert kelvin to RggbChannelVector object and pass it to Camera

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

How can I convert kelvin to RggbChannelVector object and pass it to Camera

Currently, my code is like this

```
val c2cc = Camera2CameraControl.from(camera.cameraControl)
        c2cc.clearCaptureRequestOptions()
        c2cc.captureRequestOptions = CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF)
            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_TRANSFORM_MATRIX)
            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, ColorTemperatureConverter.colorTemperature(kelvin))
            .build()
```

The formula I found on the Internet does not convert correctly, it is like this

```
fun colorTemperature(kelvin: Int): RggbChannelVector {
    val temperature = kelvin / 100f
    var red: Float
    var green: Float
    var blue: Float

    // Calculate red
    if (temperature <= 66) {
        red = 255f
    } else {
        red = temperature - 60

        red = (329.698727446 * red.toDouble().pow(-0.1332047592)).toFloat()
        if (red < 0) red = 0f
        if (red > 255) red = 255f
    }

    // Calculate green
    if (temperature <= 66) {
        green = temperature
        green = (99.4708025861 * ln(green.toDouble()) - 161.1195681661).toFloat()
        if (green < 0) {
            green = 0f
        }
        if (green > 255) {
            green = 255f
        }
    } else {
        green = temperature - 60
        green = (288.1221695283 * green.toDouble().pow(-0.0755148492)).toFloat()
        if (green < 0) green = 0f
        if (green > 255) green = 255f
    }

    // Calculate blue
    if (temperature >= 66) blue = 255f
    else if (temperature <= 19) blue = 0f
    else {
        blue = temperature - 10;
        blue = (138.5177312231 * ln(blue.toDouble()) - 305.0447927307).toFloat()
        if (blue < 0) blue = 0f
        if (blue > 255) blue = 255f
    }
    return RggbChannelVector((red / 255) * 2, green / 255, green / 255, (blue / 255) * 2)
}
```

I want to convert kelvin to RggbChannelVector object, and RggbChannelVector object can also deduce kelvin, thank you

Comment: What is the reason for scaling the computed red and blue values by 2 - that would potentially put the values out of normalized range of [0.0f, 1.0f].  Algorithm (other than constructor) matches other sources.